Grouped Stacked Bar chart in Grafana
I want to generate a grouped stacked bar chart in Grafana but dont get it to run. I managed to create a grouped chart and a stacked chart but for a grouped stacked chart I dont understand how the fitting table should look like.
Does anyone have experience or an advice for me?
My datasource is prometheus and as I know the design of the table I can probably somehow get that using Promql queries and transformations.
